# How to get out of Safe Mode

Tags: windows-7, safe-mode

I'm stuck in Safe Mode and can't get out of it.

I'm on Windows 7 and have tried F8 and msconfig. Both show options to get out of safe mode, but once I'm booted up, I'm always still in safe mode.

In other words:

1. F8: Pressed this at startup and selected "Normal Mode"
2. MSCONFIG:  Selected the "Normal Mode" radio choice.

Comment: Any events in the event logs which might explain what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Safe boot is administered in the registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Option]
"OptionValue"=dword:00000001
```

You can change OptionValue back to 0 the return to normal mode (after reboot).

A description can be found [here](http://www.tacktech.com/display.cfm?ttid=361).

Check the environment variable `SAFEBOOT_OPTION`. If it exists, this is usally an indication that you are still in safe mode. If setting `OptionValue` does not work, you can rename or delete the `\SafeBoot\Option` tree in the registry (backup!?). I don't know why, but this helped me back to normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

Go to msconfig again. Click on "Boot" and unselect "Safe boot" and select "Make all boot settings permanent".