# How to Startup Windows 8.1 without laptop screen [Only using external monitor]

Tags: windows, boot, windows-8.1, display

I am using Windows 8.1. I do not use my laptop’s screen cause it is broken, so I use a monitor instead. So what happened was,

- I ran to “msconfig”,
- and went to the “boot” tab,
- then I checked “safe boot” in the boot options,
- and then restarted my PC.

Like I said I don’t have a screen, and the monitor doesn’t display any boot screens, so I am just stuck with a blank screen. I do not know what to click or type. Later I regretted checking “safe boot”.
I just want my PC to startup normally without any of this safe mode stuff. Please help.

Comment: Can you hook up a screen to the VGA port (not HDMI port). You might see the external screen with simple VGA

Comment: This computer has no VGA port. I use a HDMI to VGA dongle cord.

Comment: You might be able to start it from another computer using a Windows RDP. It would need to be running- not necessarily logged on

Comment: Only suggestion is to edit the registry off line by connecting the hard drive to another PC>>>>>https://superuser.com/a/542752/40928

Comment: @John How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: @John How am I supposed to do that when I cannot access the first PC?

Comment: If you start the  computer even with no screen, it should land at a login screen and the you can try to RDP to it. You would need to know the computer name.

Comment: @John Really? Because I thought after pressing the on button there’s this black screen saying something like “press f1 to continue” and then after that screen is gone, it should land at a login screen. I’m not sure.

Comment: @Moab I do not know how to take out a hard drive. I will look it up later.

Comment: Look at the sides or back for a port that might be covering the hard drive.   Otherwise you need to remove the bottom cover to get at the drive.

Comment: I’ll try. I don’t like clicking around in the dark because I might accidentally reset the whole PC to factory settings.

Comment: Try booting from a USB drive with Windows PE or Linux. My experience with Ubuntu is that it recognizes a monitor (you may need to hit Enter on a black screen, though, to "Try Ubuntu without installing it"). https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1 From there, you can try getting back to Windows (or just keep Ubuntu).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That sounds risky.

Comment: Running from a Live USB makes *no change at all* to your HDD, unless you do so specifically. The whole OS is on the thumb drive.

Comment: After doing some experimenting I realize that it is not just the boot menu, the entire safe mode desktop won’t show up on a monitor for some reason. I’d like to try the method from here and take a shot in the dark https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/get-out-of-safe-mode-with-non-functioning-monitor/a2d9e303-f306-4755-8aa0-56c33256ea83 , but that doesn’t seem to work. I am still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I got my computer out of safe mode by using a sequence of keystrokes without seeing the computers screen. The steps are here: https://superuser.com/a/1520953/1133940