# How to uncheck “safeboot” from System Configuration when only using keyboard

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, external-display, safe-mode

As stated in my [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1520632/how-to-startup-windows-8-1-without-laptop-screen-only-using-external-monitor) ,

I am using Windows 8.1. I do not use my laptop’s screen cause it is broken, so I use a monitor instead. So what happened was,

- I ran to “msconfig”,
- and went to the “boot” tab,
- then I checked “safe boot” in the boot options,
- and then restarted my PC.

Apparently safe mode doesn’t show up on an external monitor. So I am stuck with a computer that won’t display anything and I need help unchecking “safe boot”. What I can do is...

- Login to windows
- Run Ctrl+R
- Type in “msconfig”
- Pressed Enter

The rest I can’t do without seeing the screen.
So I was wondering if there was a way I can do this completely using keyboard shortcuts.
I know I can use the arrow keys and tab key, but is there some shortcut that can take me to the second tab (from the general tab to the boot tab).
[system configuration window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cR2J.jpg)

By the way I tried doing it using command prompt and the method [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/stuck-in-safe-mode-broken-screen/67067dc3-8039-4191-b451-52e731c0991f). That didn’t work for me.

Comment: "so I use a monitor instead."  Your previous question remains open and you said you could not connect an external monitor.  What is going on?

Comment: @John I mean I used to use a monitor until safe mode got enabled.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to move the window to the other screen using

- Win + Shift + Arrow Right (if the monitor you want it to move to is on the right)
- Win + Shift + Arrow Left (if the target monitor is on the left

Shift Tab for this:

[image]

(notice the dashed border). Then Arrow right for Boot, press tab three times to get to Safe Boot:

[image]

Press shift tab twice to get to OK and press enter.

Your second monitor is likely not working because Safe Mode isn't loading the correct graphics driver.

edit: no there is no shortcut

Comment: I tried it, it is not working. I am assuming that I am supposed to be pressing the space bar to uncheck safe boot. Are you sure it is not press tab four times to get to Safe Boot?

Comment: Wait a minute! Never mind, it is working now! I think you just forgot the part where they ask you if you want to restart the computer, but anyway my computer is out of safe mode and seen on my monitor. Thank you so much!